# Syntax Error CGI script

Tags: python

```
name = form.getvalue('name')

age = form.getvalue('age') + 1
next_age1 = int(form["age"].value

print "Content-type: text/html"
print
print "<html><head>"
print "<p> Hello, %s</p>" % (name)
print "<p> Next year, you will be %s years old.</p>" % next_age1
```

Having trouble understanding why this doesn't work.

Can someone please help me?

Thank you!

Comment: Do include the full traceback of error messages next time. It is rather unproductive having us guess where the error might be. In this case I was able to  spot it with a short scan, but it won't always be that easy.

Answer (score 4):

You are missing a closing parenthesis:

```
 next_age1 = int(form["age"].value
 #          ----^          -------^ nothing here
```

Rule of thumb: when you get a syntax error you cannot immediately spot *on that line*, look at the previous line to see if you balanced your parenthesis and braces properly.

Comment: I fixed it but it still comes out as TypeError: unsupported operand type for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'. Still figuring out the problem. Thanks though.

Comment: The `int()` needs to be on the previous line `age = int(form.getvalue('age')) + 1`